# Can we find the generator of the Galois group of $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

$p$ is a prime. We know that $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...1$ is irreducible in Q[x]. And the splitting field of $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...1$ over $Q[x]$ is $Q(\xi_p)$-the primitive pth root of unity.

Now I want to find the Galois group of $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...1$. I know the Galois group should be the set of all the permutations of the roots. However, I want to find the generator of the Galois group. Unfortunately, I failed.

My first attempt is to try some automorphism like $\sigma$   |  $\xi_p \rightarrow \xi_p^2$. However, I find that when $p=7$, it raises counter-example, 
$\xi_7 \rightarrow \xi_7^2\rightarrow \xi_7^4\rightarrow \xi_7$ and $\xi_7^3$ never showed up.

My second attempt is try to define the generator as like the rotation generator in Dihedral group: $\sigma$   |  $\xi_p^k \rightarrow \xi_p^{k+1}$ , when $k=p-1, \sigma(\xi_p^{p-1})=\xi_p$. However, then though it seems work pretty well, $\sigma(\xi_p^k)=\sigma(\xi_p^{k_1+k_2})=\sigma(\xi_p^{k_1})\sigma(\xi_p^{k_2})=\xi_p^{k_1+1}\xi_p^{k_2+1}=\xi_p^{k+2}$, which leads to contradiction.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 4):

The generator is $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^k$, where $k$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: a primitive root modulo p? Can you explain it more concretely?

Comment: After checking wiki, this is clearly what I want! thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Define a  map $\phi:U(n) \to Gal(Q(\xi_n)/Q), a \mapsto \sigma_a$ where $\sigma_a:Gal(Q(\xi_n)/Q) \to Gal(Q(\xi_n)/Q)$ is defined by $\xi_n \to \xi_n^a.$ (Here $U(n) = (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^{\times}$ and $\xi_n$ is a primitive root of unity.) Then $\phi$ will be an isomorphism.

*Note:* See [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf) for more clarification.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for providing sources. If I know that (Z/nZ)* is isomorphic to the Galois Group. Can I find the generator? Since (Z/pZ)* is a multiplicative cyclic group. which means it has a generator . Can we get the generator for the Galois Group?

Comment: Yes! Choose a generator of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^{\times}$ and take the image of it. That will generate the Galois group.